# Using server side OAuth2 with realtime API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'd like to use realtime API with server side OAuth2 authentication flow. This would improve the user experience as it forces the user to grant access only once.
Is there a way to "inject" the server side token into the realtime API on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Drive API uses to authorize user is `access_token`. After all OAuth process, you will save credentials which will provide you `access_token` on server side. You can pass this `access_token` from server side to client side and use it in javascript client. However, you should make sure that `access_token` is sent securely to client side, over SSL, or otherwise, it will make serious security issue.